# What is the difference between char_length() and character_length()

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I get the same result using both functions. How these two functions are different from each other or they are just alias of each other

select char_length(first_name) from employee;

```
+-------------------------+
| char_length(first_name) |
+-------------------------+
|                       5 |
|                       3 |
|                       7 |
|                       6 |
|                       5 |
|                       7 |
|                       4 |
|                       4 |
|                       3 |
|                       5 |
|                       5 |
+-------------------------+
```

select character_length(first_name) from employee;

```
+------------------------------+
| character_length(first_name) |
+------------------------------+
|                            5 |
|                            3 |
|                            7 |
|                            6 |
|                            5 |
|                            7 |
|                            4 |
|                            4 |
|                            3 |
|                            5 |
|                            5 |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Take a look into: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-char-length.html

Comment: Both functions functionality is same

Comment: One involves less typing than the other

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `CHARACTER_LENGTH()` returns the length of a given string. The length is measured in characters.

The `CHARACTER_LENGTH()` is the **synonym** of `CHAR_LENGTH()`.

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL official documentation says `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the number of characters in the argument and `CHARACTER_LENGTH()` is a synonym of `CHAR_LENGTH()`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

Answer (score 1):

The CHAR_LENGTH() function returns the number of characters in its argument.

You can also use the CHARACTER_LENGTH() function, as it does the same thing.

```
SELECT  FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    DepartmentName, 
    CHAR_LENGTH(DepartmentName) AS `Char Length of Dept`,
    Email,
    CHARACTER_LENGTH(Email) AS `Char Length of Email`
    FROM employe
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(DepartmentName) > 7
    ORDER BY `Char Length of Dept`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Both are CHARACTER_LENGTH and CHAR_LENGTH Functions are same. You could visit to this site:
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_character_length.asp)